# Movieplayer keep dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to integrate a XCDMovieplayer, like you normally would with a MPMoviePlayer. The problem is that it keeps dismissing.

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
}
```

error:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <ViewController: 0xa134b80> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never present any view controller from the viewDidLoad method.

The code after your presentation call might actually make unexpected behavior and more than that your view hasn't appeared on the screen yet at that point.

Try to present your view controller in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Does not change anything. still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call super at the beginning of viewDidAppear.

`[super viewDidAppear:animated];`